# Listar datos usando select, datatables y js

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estoy tratando de hacer un reporte dinámico de unas tablas las cuales cargarán según opciones se escojan, en este caso son los clientes. Lo que deseo es añadir una opcion más donde se me muestre todo los clientes de una fecha escogida. Cabe recalcar que cuando selecciono uno por uno si me funciona. Solo Quiero añadir en el select una opcion: "Todos Los Clientes" y que al momentos de seleccionar esa opcion, muestre todos los cliente en la tabla. 
......................................................................................
......................................................................................

......................................................................................

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo

```html
<?php
//Activamos el almacenamiento en el buffer
ob_start();
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["nombre"]))
{
  header("Location: login.html");
}
else
{
require 'header.php';

if ($_SESSION['consultav']==1)
{
?>
<!--Contenido-->
      <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
      <div class="content-wrapper">        
        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="box">
                    <div class="box-header with-border">
                          <h1 class="box-title">Consulta de Ventas por fecha y cliente</h1>
                        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.box-header -->
                    <!-- centro -->
                    <div class="panel-body table-responsive" id="listadoregistros">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <label>Fecha Inicio</label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <label>Fecha Fin</label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha_fin" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-inline col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <label>Cliente</label>
                          <select name="idcliente" id="idcliente" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" required>                          
                          </select>                          
                          <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="listar()">Mostrar</button>
                        </div>
                        <table id="tbllistado" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                          <thead>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Usuario</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th>Comprobante</th>
                            <th>Número</th>
                            <th>Total Venta</th>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>                            
                          </tbody>
                          <tfoot>
                            <th>Fecha</th>
                            <th>Usuario</th>
                            <th>Cliente</th>
                            <th>Comprobante</th>
                            <th>Número</th>
                            <th>Total Venta</th>
                            <th>Impuesto</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                          </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!--Fin centro -->
                  </div><!-- /.box -->
              </div><!-- /.col -->
          </div><!-- /.row -->
      </section><!-- /.content -->

    </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
  <!--Fin-Contenido-->
<?php
}
else
{
  require 'noacceso.php';
}

require 'footer.php';
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/ventasfechacliente.js"></script>
<?php 
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Js

```js
var tabla;

//Función que se ejecuta al inicio
function init(){
 listar();
 //Cargamos los items al select cliente
 $.post("../ajax/venta.php?op=selectCliente", function(r){
             $("#idcliente").html(r);
             $('#idcliente').selectpicker('refresh');
 });
}


//Función Listar
function listar()
{
 var fecha_inicio = $("#fecha_inicio").val();
 var fecha_fin = $("#fecha_fin").val();
 var idcliente = $("#idcliente").val();

 tabla=$('#tbllistado').dataTable(
 {
  "aProcessing": true,//Activamos el procesamiento del datatables
     "aServerSide": true,//Paginación y filtrado realizados por el servidor
     dom: 'Bfrtip',//Definimos los elementos del control de tabla
     buttons: [            
              'copyHtml5',
              'excelHtml5',
              'csvHtml5',
              'pdf'
          ],
  "ajax":
    {
     url: '../ajax/consultas.php?op=ventasfechacliente',
     data:{fecha_inicio: fecha_inicio,fecha_fin: fecha_fin, idcliente: idcliente},
     type : "get",
     dataType : "json",      
     error: function(e){
      console.log(e.responseText); 
     }
    },
  "bDestroy": true,
  "iDisplayLength": 5,//Paginación
     "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]]//Ordenar (columna,orden)
 }).DataTable();
}


init();
```

CONSULTAS

```html
<?php 
//Incluímos inicialmente la conexión a la base de datos
require "../config/Conexion.php";

Class Consultas
{
 //Implementamos nuestro constructor
 public function __construct()
 {

 }

 public function comprasfecha($fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin)
 {
  $sql="SELECT DATE(i.fecha_hora) as fecha,u.nombre as usuario, p.nombre as proveedor,i.tipo_comprobante,i.serie_comprobante,i.num_comprobante,i.total_compra,i.impuesto,i.estado FROM ingreso i INNER JOIN persona p ON i.idproveedor=p.idpersona INNER JOIN usuario u ON i.idusuario=u.idusuario WHERE DATE(i.fecha_hora)>='$fecha_inicio' AND DATE(i.fecha_hora)<='$fecha_fin'";
  return ejecutarConsulta($sql);  
 }

 public function ventasfechacliente($fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin,$idcliente)
 {
  $sql="SELECT DATE(v.fecha_hora) as fecha,u.nombre as usuario, p.nombre as cliente,v.tipo_comprobante,v.serie_comprobante,v.num_comprobante,v.total_venta,v.impuesto,v.estado FROM venta v INNER JOIN persona p ON v.idcliente=p.idpersona INNER JOIN usuario u ON v.idusuario=u.idusuario WHERE DATE(v.fecha_hora)>='$fecha_inicio' AND DATE(v.fecha_hora)<='$fecha_fin' AND v.idcliente='$idcliente'";
  return ejecutarConsulta($sql);  
 }

 public function totalcomprahoy()
 {
  $sql="SELECT IFNULL(SUM(total_compra),0) as total_compra FROM ingreso WHERE DATE(fecha_hora)=curdate()";
  return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
 }

 public function totalventahoy()
 {
  $sql="SELECT IFNULL(SUM(total_venta),0) as total_venta FROM venta WHERE DATE(fecha_hora)=curdate()";
  return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
 }

 public function comprasultimos_10dias()
 {
  $sql="SELECT CONCAT(DAY(fecha_hora),'-',MONTH(fecha_hora)) as fecha,SUM(total_compra) as total FROM ingreso GROUP by fecha_hora ORDER BY fecha_hora DESC limit 0,10";
  return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
 }

 public function ventasultimos_12meses()
 {
  $sql="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(fecha_hora,'%M') as fecha,SUM(total_venta) as total FROM venta GROUP by MONTH(fecha_hora) ORDER BY fecha_hora DESC limit 0,10";
  return ejecutarConsulta($sql);
 }
}

?>
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código donde haces la consulta para cargar los datos (consultas.php)

Comment: Ya le añadi el codigo de consultas.php

Comment: Efectivamente, ahí haces las consultas, solo falta saber cómo las haces, cómo tomas los datos que vienen de AJAX  y qué hace ejecutarConsulta()... casi nada!

Comment: @Triby Me podría ayudar en ese tema, me mandaron a agregar ese campo es para mi tesis.

Comment: Personalmente, usaría una condición, así por ejemplo... si el cliente es igual a "Todos los clientes", hago una consulta solo con `($fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin)` como parámetros. En caso contrario, hago una consulta diferente con `($fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin,$id_cliente)` como parámetros.